# Cython compilation using wrong Mac OS libraries

Tags: python, macos, cython, setuptools

I'm working on a project built with Cython and have been having some interesting installation issues on some particular systems.  The problem boils down to either a mismatch in Mac OS versions, or a mismatch in my understanding of Mac OS versions.

When installing a Cython library on my system, the compilation log shows that I am using Mac OS version 10.12, even though my system tells me I am on 10.13. An excerpt of the compilation log is below:

```
creating build/temp.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.6
```

This is not a problem for me, but another user is having trouble where their system release on 10.13, but their compilation is showing 10.7 (which requires some other work arounds).

Is it possible to update this build system? Or is there something about Mac OS that I'm misunderstanding?

Is there a way to tell from a Python script which build libraries will be used?

Thank you!

**Edit:**

Output of platform information:

```
>>> python -c "import platform; print(platform.mac_ver())"
('10.13.6', ('', '', ''), 'x86_64')

>>> python -c "import distutils.util; print(distutils.util.get_platform())"
macosx-10.12-x86_64
```

Comment: The version mismatch is odd; when you run `python -c "import platform; print(platform.mac_ver())"` from the terminal, what do you get?

Comment: I edited the original question with the output: `('10.13.6', ('', '', ''), 'x86_64')`

Comment: So Python correctly recognizes the platform version. What you see is the output of `distutils.util.get_platform` - reproduce that via `python -c "import distutils.util; print(distutils.util.get_platform())"` (also, make sure to use the correct executable, should be `python3.6` in your case). On MacOS, it doesn't display the version of the platform you're running on, but the version of the platform your Python distribution was built on. This ensures that `distutils` uses the same ABI for building C extensions as the Python distribution you will be using the compiled extension object with.

Comment: Interesting! I get different output for this: `macosx-10.12-x86_64`.  Is there a way to update this so they match?

Comment: In general, building a "universal" wheel on MacOS is a hairy topic; if you want to build a wheel on your machine that installs and runs on a wide range of Python distributions on other MacOS machines, the rule of thumb is to get a Python distribution where `distutils.util.get_platform` outputs `macosx-10.6-intel`. This ABI seems to be the most compatible one; however, judging by your output, it looks like you have the brewed Python 3 installed; from my experience, it is not suitable for building universal wheels.

Comment: hmm interesting.  If I wanted to update my Python so `get_platform` outputs 10.13, would I just have to reinstall it? Or would brew install the same one again?  Currently, we've found the wheel installs on 10.7 with a particular flag set and on new versions only without the flag.  It would also be okay if we could easily update the 10.7 computer to have a newer version.

Comment: If you want both versions to match, you can build your own Python distribution from the source code, but beware that C extensions built with that distribution will not be compatible with older ABIs.

Comment: Reinstalling Python will bump the `distutils` platform version only if the distribution you're installing was rebuilt using a newer ABI; otherwise, this number will not change.

Comment: If you want you and the other user to have identical ABIs, just install from the same distribution using [same versioned installer from python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/); this is the preferred way of installing Python on MacOS anyway, while the brewed version is hardly suitable for development IMO.

Answer (score 1):

**My context**

A similar issue came up with Big Sur (macOS 10.16), python3.6, and cython.
Checking the build directory of cython (`.pyxbld`) I find `temp.macOSX-10.7` builds and files, which apparently is incompatible with 10.16.

**Some Explanations why this is going on**

Under the hood cython uses distutils to determine the platform version (as opposed to other things). https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/distutils/util.py So then what's up with distutils?

After a lot of searching (including this post), I came across a really interesting and good post (although from 2014) that explains this phenomenon.
https://lepture.com/en/2014/python-on-a-hard-wheel

Basically, it has to do with how distutils was build and that it has hard-coded platform tags... (this also applies to the wheel files).

**Solution (kinda)**

It seems that the solution is to :

1. reinstall python (and then all packages)
2. make sure that `python -c "import distutils.util; print(distutils.util.get_platform())" macosx-10.12-x86_64` outputs a correct version.

**Edit**

Apparently On Big Sur with Anaconda this solution does not work yet... (work in progress will update if solution on Anaconda will work) [Fri 20 Nov 2020]

Comment: Pls see and give suggestions for this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75920613/mac-application-not-running-on-different-chip-and-os?noredirect=1#comment133918885_75920613

Comment: How can one specify Cython to create "universal2" modules for Mac, as mentioned here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/building-a-universal-macos-binary

Comment: Hi @rnso the above mentioned question seems to be removed. Could you link another question. Thank you.

Comment: I could solve my problem using instructions on this page: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/building-a-universal-macos-binary